# Sonata Admin - disable translations

Tags: symfony, locale, translation, sonata-admin, sonata

I would like to disable `SonataAdminBundle` translations and it to be only in english no matter what other locale is set.

Is there a way to handle through config? Or should I force english locale on every Kernel Request? Maybe rewrite translation files?